# Merging rows in to a single record

Tags: ms-access

A database authored externally has some data I want to match up over 2 tables:

Table A:

- ID1 (number)
- ID2 (number)
- Fld1 (text)

Table B:

- ID1 (number)
- Type (number)
- Fld2 (text)
- Fld3 (text)

The only common field to join on is ID1, however, I really want all data matched on ID2 records.

Joining the tables on ID1 gives me the following result:

```
| ID1 | ID2 | Type |   Fld1    |   Fld2    |   Fld3    |
--------------------------------------------------------
|  1  |  1  |  1   |   Data1   |   Data1   |           |
|  2  |  1  |  2   |           |           |   Data1   |
|  3  |  2  |  1   |   Data1   |   Data1   |           |
|  4  |  2  |  2   |           |           |   Data1   |
```

What I need is a query that results in:

```
| ID1 | ID2 | Type |   Fld1    |   Fld2    |   Fld3    |
--------------------------------------------------------
|  ?  |  1  |  ?   |   Data1   |   Data1   |   Data1   |
|  ?  |  2  |  ?   |   Data1   |   Data1   |   Data1   |
```

I've put "?" for ID1 and Type fields as I'm not really sure what result these would merge down to (ultimately I'm not fussed about these 2 fields, I really just want ID2 and the 3 "Fld~" fields).

What method is there for achieving this?

**Additional notes after accepted answer:**

As Remou recommended, using the aggregate function MAX on the text fields and grouping by the ID field I wanted to use worked. However, I didn't mention in my original illustration of the issue that I was also filtering on a couple of fields as well.

Even if these fields are not selected for the query, they need to have their "total" function set to "Where" in the query's design view to ensure they become part of the SQL's `WHERE` clause. By default design view will set them to "Group By", which put them in to the `HAVING` clause (not what I wanted).

[image: Totals in Design View]

This is the full SQL I arrived at that gave me what I needed:

```sql
SELECT A.Learner_Id, 
       Max(B.AddLine1) AS Address1, 
       Max(B.AddLine2) AS Address2, 
       Max(B.AddLine3) AS Address3, 
       Max(B.AddLine4) AS Address4, 
       Max(A.PostCode) AS AddPostCode
FROM LearnerContact As A LEFT JOIN PostAdd As B ON A.LearnerContact_Id = B.LearnerContact_Id
WHERE (((A.LocType)=1 Or (A.LocType)=2) AND ((A.ContType)=2))
GROUP BY A.Learner_Id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Max might suit:

```
SELECT t.ID2, 
       Max(t.Fld1) AS MaxOfFld1, 
       Max(t.Fld2) AS MaxOfFld2, 
       Max(x.Fld3) AS MaxOfFld3
FROM aTable t 
INNER JOIN bTable x
ON t.ID1 = x.ID1
GROUP BY t.ID2;
```

Comment: I have tried MAX, but it didn't seem to work. I'll post my full SQL in moment. Also: Fld3 is part of Table B, which is joined on ID1 between the 2 tables. I've also got some other criteria filtering the query.

Comment: What does not work about Max? The query fails or you get the wrong results?

Comment: I've added the SQL I used for MAX to the original question. I'm getting the error `Cannot have Memo, OLE or Hyperlink Object fields in aggregate argument (PostAdd.AddLine1)`. I think that means I might have to change these address fields to short text. (This database is terrible...)

Comment: So AddLine1 is a memo? I think that is probably unnecessarily long, you could use `LEFT(AddLine1,255)` in an aggregate, you might lose some data, but I doubt it.

Comment: You can always check `Len(AddLine1)` first.

Comment: It's ok, I've changed them all to short text (this database I'm has this memo text problem throughout unfortunately). I'm now getting results, but only 63 records... should be 1000. I've posted the SQL I'm using with MAX functions in my answer.. I think the `HAVING` clause is causing an issue here (I didn't mention it in my initial illustrations, but I need to filter some of the fields as well).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47943/discussion-between-remou-and-matt-hall)

Comment: ahhh.. I set the "Total" option to "Where" in design mode and that's giving me the final piece I'm after. Thanks for your help.